# IIS 7 error: State server stops listening

Tags: iis-7

Any clue what's happened with IIS and ASP .NET 4 ?

Many many thanks!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The state sever, which is used to save session state in memory, has been stopped. There should be another log entry telling you why.